# Which app distribution method I must use for this app?

Tags: ios, developer-program, enterprise

Im making an app for my enterprise but we dont know yet which ditribution method to use. The app is for employees, <-- This is not a problem, we can use Enterprise Membership, the problem is that the app is also going to be used by the family of the employees, so Enterprise is not an option because we wanted to upload the an into the intranet but that way the families couldnt have access to the app.

So my question is: With enterprise account, we can upload the app into the public enterprise page? Or for this situation, is better to use a normal Developer Account and publish the app into the App Store?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iOS Enterprise agreement has the following clause:

> Distribute Provisioning Profiles only to Your Employees and only in conjunction with Your 
>   Internal Use Applications for the purpose of developing and testing Your Internal Use 
>   Applications;

In addition it states:

> Allow Your Customers to use Your Internal Use Applications
>   on Deployme
>   nt Devices
>   , but only 
>   (i) on Your physical premises and/or on Your Permitted Entity’s physical premises, or (ii) in other 
>   locations, provided all such use is under the direct supervision and physical control of Your 
>   Employees or Permitted Users (e.g., a sal
>   es presentation to a Customer)

Hence for your user base, it would would not be right to distribute apps with enterprise license. Distribute the app through the app store with some kind of authentication mechanism.

You have also host some kind of registration mechanism on your intranet, where the employees would generate user IDs and passwords for themselves and their families.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of distributing apps is by using a mobile device management software. You can push apps to any device which is managed by the MDM. Usually what MDM does is a complete device management but some vendors like Hexnode MDM provides the [app distribution](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/distribute-app-without-app-store/) feature alone.